# Prove that $\tau(n) \leq 2\sqrt{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm looking at the following problem:

Prove that for a positive integer $n$, $$\tau(n) \leq 2 \sqrt{n}$$ where $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

So my idea was to split the set of the number of divisors of $n$ into two subsets: One subset containing the divisors those less than $\sqrt{n}$ and the other subset containing the divisors larger than $\sqrt{n}$ and argue that there must be at most $\sqrt{n}$ in each subset. But I simply can't seem to find that argument! Can you help?

Comment: Can you somehow find a pairing between the two sets of divisors?

Comment: You can replace $\le$ with $<$.

Comment: The optimal result is $\tau (n) \leq \sqrt {3n}.$ I'm just saying. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/43103/what-is-the-lower-bound-for-highly-composite-numbers/43105#43105 Next of the same type is $$ \tau(n) \leq 24 \left(\frac{n}{315}\right)^{1/3} $$

Comment: Is there any way you guys do these searches for the questions to see if it has been asked before? Because I did a search for all kinds of things and nothing showed up. Thanks for all your replies! The solution is so simple!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: You can pair d with $\frac{n}{d}$, where d is any positive divisor of n.

(When n is a perfect square, $\sqrt{n}$ gets paired with itself.)